# Set gcc and g++ optimization flags permanently

Tags: gcc, compiler-optimization

I'm running a x86 kernel on an x64 machine. I would like to compile libraries for a i586 processor. During compilation, some libraries use i686 optimization, so want to set `-mtunes=i586`, `-march=i586` and `-O3` flags for all of libraries even if they explicitly declare something else in their makefiles.

Somehow I want to set compiler flags permanently...

Comment: This doesn't sound like a very good thing to want...  If a makefile explicitly specifies particular flags, it's probably for a reason.

Comment: What do you want to do with Makefiles that try to change `-O3` to `-O2` because the code just plain won't work with `-O3`?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: I'm compiling openCV for rb-110 x86 embeded board. Installing a debian on micro-SD card, I'm running it on my PC. but when compiling things, binaries are i686. I'm looking for a way to force them to be i586 and be optimized of course.

Comment: @hvd: I have a very very weak processor, trying to optimize everything. Are you sure if `-O3` will not work?

Comment: @SorushRabiee: yes, some packages can break (sometimes very subtly) with `-O3` on some versions of GCC. `-Os` is possibly more appropriate for weaker CPUs too.

Comment: @hvd: hmm. I think I should forget optimization. But have to force compiler not to generate i686 code, because afaik i686 may fail to run on an i586 box. correct?

Comment: @SorushRabiee Correct. However, this is not really any different from compiling for non-x86 platforms. Software that unconditionally forces `-march=i686` won't work on i586 any more than they will on some ARM processor. Or is the problem that your compiler's default target is i686?

Comment: I thinks it's because of x86. the processor of my PC is x64_86 (Core i5)

Answer (score 4):

Regardless of whether you *should* do this, here's the easiest way to do it:

1. Create a new file with the following contents:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh

   exec /usr/bin/gcc "$@" -O3 -mtunes=i586 -march=i586
   ```

   *Change /usr/bin/gcc to your actual compiler if that's not right on your system.*
2. Save it as `~/bin/gcc`.
3. Make the new script executable:

   chmod +x ~/bin/gcc
4. Repeat to create another file for g++.
5. Add `~/bin` to the **start** of your path:

   ```
   export PATH=~/bin:$PATH
   ```
6. Compile your project. Whenever your new scripts are on the path they will override whatever the makefile says.

Hope that helps.

P.S. The *best* way to  do it (rather than the easiest) would probably be to mess with the compiler's "specs" file, but it's much harder to explain and do.